# Why is "flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE" giving a syntax error while making a face recognition model?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am building a facerecognition model using opencv.

my piece of code for which I'm gettung an error is:

```py
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        s.caleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
```

ERROR is :

```
 flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please helppp!!!

code syntax was right according to me, dont know why am i getting this error

Comment: is that the verbatim piece of code? Because there is no closing parenthesis for the function call.

Comment: Also `cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE` in your code, but `cv.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE` in your error message?

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple spelling mistake.

Change

```
s.caleFactor=1.1,
```

to `scaleFactor=1.1`